# Mathematically, what is the difference between "tosses two coins simultaneously" and "tossing two coin successively" ?

Tags: probability

Mathematically, what is the difference between "tosses two coins simultaneously" and "tossing two coin successively" ? Can it be seen (in a certain way) as the same experiment ?

**Tossing two coin simultaneously**

$$\Omega_1 =\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\}$$
and the even space is given by $$\mathcal F_1=\sigma \Big(\{(H,H)\}, \big\{(T,H),(H,T)\big\},\{(T,T)\}\Big),$$
with probability measure $$\mathbb P_1\{(H,H)\}=\mathbb P_1\{(T,T)\}=\frac{1}{4}\quad \text{and}\quad \mathbb P\{(H,T),(T,H)\}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

also, it can be seen as

$$\Omega _2=\big\{\{H,H\},\{T,T\},\{T,H\}\big\},$$
with $\mathcal F_2=2^{\Omega _2}$ and $$\mathbb P_2\{H,H\}=\mathbb P_2\{T,T\}=\frac{1}{4}\quad \text{and}\quad \mathbb P_2\{H,T\}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

---

Here, we can de describe the experiment by to different probability space $$(\Omega _1,\mathcal F_1,\mathbb P_1)\quad \text{and}\quad (\Omega _2,\mathcal F_2,\mathbb P_2).$$
But since they describe the same experiment, are these space the same ? If no, which space is "better" or "worst" than the other one ? What are the connections between them ?

---

**Tossing two coins successively**

$$\Omega =\{(H,H),(T,H),(H,T),(T,T)\},$$
and the event space is $\mathcal F=2^\Omega $ and the probability measure is $\mathbb P\{\omega \}=\frac{1}{4}$ for all $\omega \in \Omega $.

We can see clearly that $\mathcal F_1\subset \mathcal F$ and that $\mathbb P_1=\mathbb P|_{\mathcal F_1}$. So $\mathbb P_1$ can be extended on $\mathcal F$ by $\mathbb P$.

---

So, does "tossing two coins simultaneously" can be seen as "tossing two coins successively" in the sens that "tossing two coins successively" extend "tossing two coins simultaneously ?

The thing is that $(\Omega _2,\mathcal F_2, \mathbb P_2)$ can be extended on $\mathbb F$ by setting $\alpha =\mathbb P\{(T,H)\}$ and $\beta =\mathbb P\{(H,T)\}=\beta $ and impose the condition $\alpha +\beta =\frac{1}{2}$. Take for example $\alpha =0.1$ and thus $\beta =0.4$. What is going to be this experience ? The coin are tossed successively, but having $(H,T)$ and $(T,H)$ with different probability... how could that work ?

Comment: there is no difference, assuming that the result of each coin is independent of the result of the other.